# Microsoft equivalent of reCAPTCHA

Tags: security, recaptcha

What is Microsoft equivalent of Google reCAPTCHA? This is for spam prevention during the sign up process.

Comment: A little more detail would really help here. What is your rationale for wanting a Microsoft equivalent of Google reCAPTCHA? Are you saying that you are a Microsoft house and it is easier to pay MS for this than it is to set Google up as a vendor. Or do you have a specific compatibility issue?

Comment: FYI, if you can't use Google reCAPTCHA, then hCAPTCHA (https://www.hcaptcha.com/) is a great alternative.